# rspec bugs when trying to run rake

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I'm trying to teach myself some ruby using the app academy tutorials and after doing the readings, installing rvm,rubygems and rspec2 when I even try to run the first most basic code (00_hello) with rake I get the whole error :

```
 (in /home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby)
/home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby/rspec_config.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `color=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x0000000293dee0> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core.rb:67:in `configure'
    from /home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby/rspec_config.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `require'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `block in requires='
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `map'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `requires='
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `block in configure'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `each'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:17:in `run'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
ruby -S bundle exec rspec -I/home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby/00_hello -I/home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config "/home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb" failed
/home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:117:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in initialize'
/home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
/home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:109:in `block in initialize'
Tasks: TOP => default => spec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried to google some of the errors, but with no success. I had previously another error with the rake file using rspec v2 and the current version is 3.0.0, so I had to install the older and I think it might be another setup problem. Thanks if someone can help me or direct me.

rspec_config.rb file :

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
    c.fail_fast = true
    c.color = true
end
```

hello.rb file:

```
def hello
   "Hello!"
end

def greet(who)
   "Hello, #{who}!"
end
```

**UPDATE**

Getting new error as :-

While I changed `c.color = true` to `c.color_enabled = true`

```
(in /home/deadpool/Documents/learn_ruby)
the hello function says hello (FAILED - 1)

Failures: 1) the hello function says hello Failure/Error: 
Unable to find matching line from backtrace undefined method run_all' for []:Array 
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:116:inrun_hook_filtered' 
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:176:in eval_before_alls'
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:231:inrun'
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:26:in block (2 levels) in run'
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:26:inmap'
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:26:in block in run' 
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:11:inreport'
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:23:in run' 
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:inrun_in_process' 
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in run'
# /home/deadpool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:inblock in autorun'
```

**UPDATE**

hello_spec.rb file :

```
require "hello"

describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    hello.should == "Hello!"
  end
end

describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    greet("Alice").should == "Hello, Alice!"
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    greet("Bob").should == "Hello, Bob!"
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
So, I updated rspec to v3.0.0 and changed Rakefile `gem 'rspec', '~>3.0.0'` and `c.color = true` back. Everything is working now(getting some deprecation warnings, but nothing critical), getting the output that is in the tutorial. Guess I just had to updae my rspec and change the version in the Rakefile. Thank you so much :)

Comment: show your `.rb` file to us.

Comment: Just show us the content of `rspec_config.rb` file.

Comment: Post this in your question itself not in comment..

Comment: Use `c.color_enabled = true` and let me know the result.

Comment: Please don't change the original question..

Comment: Use as **UPDATE** and then ask again or ask in a separate question.

Comment: Now show the Rspec code you wrote to test your file.

Comment: As per your Rspec version, your test code is correct. Dunno why the error you got..

Comment: I read somewhere I should update to v3.0.0. Will try it.

Comment: @LexxN.. Yes, better to upgrade. No need to use so old version, you are using.

Comment: @ArupRakshit How to mark as solved and answered, i'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error log is showing you are in *rspec-core-2.0.0* version and your error is saying -

```
rspec_config.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `color=' for 
#<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x0000000293dee0> (NoMethodError)
```

Now [Deprecate config options](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/0f786c3367b658918a9c499d10cc915781887687) confirms that below versions of *2.99.0.rc1 / 2014-05-18* or *2.99.0* methods were - `#color_enabled`, `#color_enabled=` and `#color?`. Which are changed since *2.99.0* to `#color`, `#color=` and `#color_enabled?`.

I got the information from the *changelog* as I linked -

> Deprecate #color_enabled, #color_enabled= and #color? in favour of #color, #color= and #color_enabled? output. (Jon Rowe)

Thus you need to write as

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
    c.fail_fast = true
    c.color_enabled = true
end
```

Regarding your new error, I found it as a [`bug undefined method`run_all' for []:Array`](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/788351). Which has been fixed [in this patch](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/84bb15d7d355f9e56c9a0d1898fcfb7a9a9bde23). Check this [Rspec issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/258).

My suggestion use [Rspec 3.0](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs), at least you will be happy. In this case revert the `color_enabled` to `color`.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: @LexxN Your error is new, not the previous one. Which confirms that, this answer solve the previous error.

Comment: so I should ask another question for the new error?

Comment: @LexxN What I asked in your post comment tell me.. Show your Rspec code you wrote to test your method.

Comment: I'm testing it with hello.rb file